# unable to read from new table in Amplify Studio

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am new to React so forgive my basic questions...

I inherited a piece of code that connects to an amplify studio set of tables and that works fine. Now i added a new table via schema.graphql, schema.js, index.js and index.d.ts (is that the right way?).

i duplicated the code which is used to read from another table and am pretty sure that its correct, however when i try to get the data into a pull down menu, i get an error which is unable to retrieve the data.

this is the retrieve code:

```
import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import { InverterTechnicalData as InverterTechnicalDataAmplify } from 'models/index';
import { useQuery, UseQueryResult } from 'react-query';
import { showToaster } from 'slices/layout/toastLayoutSlice';
import { useDispatch } from 'src/store/hooks';
import { ToastActions } from 'types/toasterTypes';

const InverterTechnicalDataCacheKey = 'InverterTechnicalDataCacheKey';

export const useGetInverterTechnicalData = (): UseQueryResult<InverterTechnicalDataAmplify[], string | Error> => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return useQuery([InverterTechnicalDataCacheKey], async () => {
        try {
            const result = await DataStore.query(InverterTechnicalDataAmplify);
            return result;
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(
                showToaster({
                    message: 'Unable to retrieve data, try again',
                    key: Math.random(),
                    action: ToastActions.Dismiss,
                }),
            );
        }
    });
};
```

I assume it has to do with the generation of the table in amplify, but i dont know enough about it so if anybody has any pointers that would be great.

thanks,

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: in the interface when i trigger the code, i just get the message above, "unable to retreive data, try again" - the text obvioulsy is something i created myself. 

how can i better understand the actual error?

Comment: Here you catch a variable called `error` but never reveal the contents of it. You can either `console.log(error)` or add it to your toast as `JSON.stringify(error)`

Comment: The message i get now is:

Comment: NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.

Comment: Have a look over https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8488

Comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5130